# What is meant by 'a static area'?

Tags: c, static, manpage

What is meant by 'a static area' in [`man GETPWNAM(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwnam.3.html#RETURN_VALUE)?

> The return value may point to a static area, and may be
> overwritten by subsequent calls to getpwent(3), getpwnam(), or
> getpwuid().  (Do not pass the returned pointer to free(3).)

This might be a really trivial question but I'm curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that there is a, basically, global variable whose memory is shared by all the mentioned functions, and all those functions returns a pointer to that shared variable.

So if you do e.g.

```
struct passwd *pwd1 = getpwnam("foo");
struct passwd *pwd2 = getpwnam("bar");
```

then there is a chance that `pwd1 == pwd2`, and the second call to `getpwnam` have overwritten the data in the structure collected by the first call.